# How do I install calipers with no locking mechanism to the piston correctly?

Tags: honda, brake-calipers

I bought rear pads for my Honda CRV 2008 today and the owner of the store said they suit my car.

I installed them and there is a squealing noise and no pressure on the brake pedal. These brake pads I bought have no caliper piston locking clips like the existing ones had. So I have no idea how they are supported to move in and out with the piston?

New ones look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMU0U.jpg

Old pads look like this (notice the clips)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk9vT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be:

> So I have no idea how they are supported to move in and out with the
> piston?

Disc brake pads are only pushed into the rotor by the calipers.  There is no "pull back" from the caliper pistons.  Disc brakes remain very lightly in contact with the rotors all the time.

If you have to pedal pressure that's because you need to bleed the brake lines after servicing.  But before doing that, try pumping the brake pedal a number of times and see if the pressure builds.

Comment: Hi. After installing these pads I here a constant squel. Even without brake applied. Would this be due to the lack of clips that go inside the piston?

Comment: Unlikely in my opinion.  Perhaps you might post some photos of your installed pads.  It's possible you did it improperly.

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll post pictures tomorrow when I take the pads off

Comment: Examine those pads when removed. If they show signs of incomplete contact to each side of a rotor, the rotor wasn't machined to remove wear and tear creating a taper and squealing. Occasionally, perfectly good disc brakes squeal but less often than taking short cuts on diy repairs. All disc brakes float freely, making light contact with rotors. This doesn't wear them down and keeps rotors clean automatically. Disc brake repairs by professionals usually include machining rotors when necessary or they're replaced. Liability issues dictates zero short cuts in brake repairs

Comment: hey guys thanks for your answers. I went back to the brake and clutch shop and they told me they gave me the wrong pads and appoligized. I put some greese on the rail and no squeeking and working good now.  Thank you very much for the info and advice!